# QtCreator зависает при удалённой отладке Linux Device

Tags: qtcreator

При отладке QtCreator (Windows версия начиная с 11) удалённой linux-программы, возникает проблема после такой последовательности:

1. запускаем программу или просто делаем deploy
2. перезагружаем устройство
3. пытаемся запустить программу или просто сделать deploy

всё на третьем шаге глухо виснет, только закрывать через TaskManager

1 и 3 шаги можно заменить на нажатие кнопки [Test] в настройке Linux Device

Встречался ли кто-нибудь с такой проблемой? Пока помогает только откат к версии 10.0.2.

Такое подозрение, что он пытается пользоваться предварительно открытой ssh сессией, хотя в документации написано, что для Windows каждый раз открывается новая...